# why isnt this function returning any values?

Tags: javascript, function, return

i need to pass the variables to another function, but it isnt returning anything.
NOTE: it doesnt return anything to the outside, but if i do a document.write inside the function it works perfectly..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//funtion1
    if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Location);
        }
    function Location(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    return (latitude,longitude);
        }


//function2
    function initialize() {
        document.write(latitude);
        document.write(longitude);}
</script>
```

Comment: i know im not calling it, but still it works!! it just isnt outputting the values

Comment: I'd recommend reading some basic JavaScript tutorials, rather than jumping in at the deep end and trying to do something without grasping the simplest concepts of the language.

Answer (score 9):

You're misunderstanding a few concepts.

First, `return (a, b)` will evaluate to `return b`. The comma operator is almost never needed. If you want to return an array, use `return [a, b]`.

Secondly, `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. It will execute `Location` if it has found the position. So at the time you call `document.write`, the position has not been fetched yet.

Lastly, you're not using the return value at all. If you want to use the return value of a function, use e.g. `var result = func(...)`. However, in this case this doesn't make sense.

I don't exactly know what you're after, but anything that relies on the position should be put inside the callback (`Location` in this case). Only when the callback is called the poision is available. In this callback returning something is pointless since the return value is not used for `getCurrentPosition`.

**Edit:** Looking at your code, you want something like this instead of `return`ing:

```
function Location(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    useValuesForSomethingElse(latitude, longitude); // call other function with position data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return only one value from the function. If you want to return more than one value, create a object and set the values in it to return. Otherwise use arrays to return more than one value

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your code into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      document.write(latitude, longitude);
    });
  }
</script>
```

The function you pass into `getCurrentPosition()` will get executed when the position is retrieved. Only then you have access to the position and you are able to set `latitude` and `longitude` variables and write them into the document.

In your code `getCurrentPosition()` will be called, then immediately after that `document.write(latitude,longitude);` will get executed which is way before the `latitude` and `longitude` are available. You must move your `document.write()` into the `Location()`.

**Update 1** (based on comments):

If you don't want to do `document.write()` inside the callback function, but you want call another function, then you must call it from the callback function.

It will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      myFunction(latitude, longitude);
    });
  }

  function myFunction(latitude, longitude) {
    // you can do here anything you wish
    document.write(latitude, longitude);
  }
</script>
```

**Update 2** (based on comments and updated question):

A way how to handle loading the map based on the position is to to call `initialize()` from `Location()` with `latitude` and `longitude` as parameters. To make sure the code working with HTML elements is executed when page is loaded you can execute inside `Location()`.

```
window.onload = intialize(latitude, longitude);
```

See **[this](http://jsbin.com/uxobuk/4/edit#html,live)** for a complete code.

Comment: what i want is not to do a document.write() inside the function!
i want to get the values and use them in another funciton

Comment: thanks, it seems like it is exactly hwat i wanted, ill test it right away!

Comment: @jony: here is the running code for you to play with: http://jsbin.com/evoyoj/edit#html,live

Comment: yeah, it runned fine, but now passing the variables to the google map api is being a problem...

Comment: the problem is that google maps seem to have to be called on body load

Comment: @jony: See my updated answer and [jsbin snippet](http://jsbin.com/uxobuk/4/edit#html,live).

Answer (score 2):

The `.getCurrentPosition()` function executes asynchronously and then calls `Location()` when done. In the meantime, whatever comes after the call to `getCurrentPosition()` will execute but will have no results to work with. This also means whatever you return from `Location()` will not be used by any other code.

So you need to call your other function from within `Location()`.

(Also, talking about function returns in general, you need to return a single value or an object/array. A comma-separated list of return values will in effect just return the last one in the list.)

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` calls the passed function asynchronously as soon as the position is available (e.g. after the user accepted the prompt if the site may know the position).

You need to continue your code in the `Location` function - and do not return anything as it will not be used anywhere.

Comment: well since it seems that im not able to output the values ill be forced to put the function2 inside the function1, but its not at all what i wanted. my code will get much thicker and heavier..

Comment: That's exactly what you **should** do... You could just call another function and pass the parameters to it.